# pyspark cast all columns of a certain data type to another

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with a certain number of date columns. I want to cast them all to timestamp, without having to worry about the exact names of the columns. So what I want is something in line of: "Cast all date columns to timestamp and keep the same column names"

I know that for one column it would be:

```py
df = df.withColumn('DATUM', df['DATUM'].cast('timestamp'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop and detect when the type is `date` and perform the cast only for those cases.

```
for col in df.dtypes:
  if(col[1] == 'date'):
    df = df.withColumn(col[0],df[col[0]].cast('timestamp'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop, and cast to timestamp

```
df.select(
    *[df[col_name].cast('timestamp') for col_name in df.columns]
)
```